# How can I properly using Comparables in this situation?

Tags: java, algorithm, generics

I'm doing an exercise from Sedgewick's Algorithms textbook, the exercise is to find the number of compares for quicksort. Below is my code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class quickSortCompareCheck {

    private static int numberOfCompares;


    private static Comparable[] generateArray(int n) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Comparable[] arr = new Comparable[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    private static class QuickSort {

        private static void quickSort(Comparable[] arr) {
            StdRandom.shuffle(arr);
            quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        }

        private static void quickSort(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
            if (lo >= hi) return;
            int partition = partition(arr, lo, hi);
            quickSort(arr, lo, partition - 1);
            quickSort(arr, partition + 1, hi);
        }

        private static int partition(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
            Comparable pivot = arr[lo];
            int i = lo;
            int j = hi + 1;
            while (true) {
                numberOfCompares++;

                while (less(arr[++i], pivot)) {
                    if (i == hi) break;
                    numberOfCompares++;
                }

                numberOfCompares++;

                while(less(pivot, arr[--j])) {
                    if (j == lo) break;
                    numberOfCompares++;
                }

                if (i >= j) break;
                exchange(arr, i, j);
            }
            exchange(arr, lo, j);
            return j;
        }

        private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
            return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
        }

        private static void exchange(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
            Comparable temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sizes = {100,1000,10000};
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            int size = sizes[i];
            double exp = 2 * size * Math.log(size);
            Comparable[] arr = generateArray(sizes[i]);
            QuickSort.quickSort(arr);
            StdOut.println("Expected compares is: " + exp);
            StdOut.println("Actual compares is: " + numberOfCompares);
            numberOfCompares = 0;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
quickSortCompareCheck.java:10: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
    private static Comparable[] generateArray(int n) {
                   ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:12: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        Comparable[] arr = new Comparable[n];
        ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:12: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        Comparable[] arr = new Comparable[n];
                               ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:21: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        private static void quickSort(Comparable[] arr) {
                                      ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:26: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        private static void quickSort(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
                                      ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:33: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        private static int partition(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
                                     ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:34: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
            Comparable pivot = arr[lo];
            ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:59: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
                                    ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:59: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Comparable
        private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
                                                  ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Comparable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
quickSortCompareCheck.java:60: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type Comparable
            return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
                              ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
10 warnings
```

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm not sure how to fix the code, I got it to work using the Integer class instead of Comparable since Integer implements Comparable, but I'd like to get my code working as it is. There's a solution (https://github.com/reneargento/algorithms-sedgewick-wayne/blob/master/src/chapter2/section3/Exercise6.java) to the exercise that is similar to mine but the person generates the random array differently. Can someone please school me on how to fix this?

Comment: I haven't read through your code entirely, but if you're asking why you're getting those *warnings* (they are not errors), then read through this: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Hint: Read a tutorial about *generics*.

Comment: Dont use a generic array to begin with, that is never a good idea( unless a specialized internal library, which this isn't)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal of information available about generics but it is not always so easy to grasp so I decided to make 'a little case study' here.

Check out [Java doc for Comparable<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). Excerpt from the very beginning of it:

> **Interface Comparable<T>**
>
> Type Parameters:
> T - the type of objects that this object may be compared to

The warnings are because you have not declared the type **T** for your comparable. The purpose of declaring the type for any generic class is that it allows compiler to check - at the compile time - that generic type is used correctly.

If you do not provide the type this check cannot be done and it issues these warnings in every place you have anything without giving the type so being a **raw type**. It means that there is no guarantee that there would be some wrong instance of - in your case - `Comparable` that is used.

In your case the type would be `Integer`. So like `Comparable<Integer>`. However it would require some refactoring of your code and there would not be a point since `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>` so it is a `Comparable<Integer>` itself.

As a conclusion you could - for example - just replace occurences of `Comparator` with `Integer`.

It is also possible to make this whole stuff generic so that it could be used for `String` or any other comparable but as mentioned it requires some refactoring and is out of scope of this question and answer.

**Disclaimer**: I did not test your code in any manner so test it.

*(btw: checked Java docs also that StdRandom & StdOut accept ints)*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I actually did get the code to work before I posted this using `Integer`. However, as you mentioned, I wanted to make this whole stuff generic. I replaced with `Comparable<Integer>` wherever I used `Comparable`, now I'm getting an error for the arr initialization line in the generateArray method, I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be there and that if just simply replacing with `Comparable<Integer>` is the correct refactor.